# C struct contains dirty data, I can't spot why?

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code that performs an insert into a struct that I called symrec (which stands for symbol record).

```
symrec *createSymStruct(char const * varName, type * type, symrec ** tabella){
symrec * s;
printf("creating new varibale for struct\n");
char * variableName = malloc(strlen(varName)+1);
strcpy(variableName,varName);
s = getsymStruct(variableName, *tabella);
if (s == 0){
    printf("putting symbol into table\n");
    s = putsymStruct(variableName, NULL, &(*tabella));
}
s->tipo = type;
return s;
}
```

and the called function which is

```
symrec 
*putsymStruct(char const * identifier, type * tipo, symrec ** tabella){
  printf("\tputting symbol in the table\n");
  symrec *ptr = (symrec *) malloc (sizeof (symrec));
  ptr->name = (char *) malloc (strlen (identifier) + 1);
  strcpy (ptr->name,identifier);
  ptr->tipo = (type*)malloc(sizeof(type));
  ptr->tipo = tipo;
  ptr->next = (symrec*)tabella;
  *tabella = ptr;
  return ptr;
}
```

I have only one function call of this type for the moment and I builded a function to print out values of the symbol table

```
void readTable(symrec * tabella){
printf("PRINTING TABLE\n");
if(tabella == NULL){
    printf("table is empty\n");
}
symrec *ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
    printf("_");
}
printf("\n");
for (ptr = tabella; ptr != (symrec *) 0;
     ptr = (symrec *)ptr->next){

    printf("|\t%*s\t|\n",20,ptr->name);
}

printf("\n");
}
```

surprisingly when the table is printed I find a variable that I didn't put, it is more likely a memory space not cleaned or something in the declaration that I'm doing wrong..The following  is the output.. Can you help me spotting out where the trouble is? Any hint? Didn't I clean the memory during allocation or what?

```
PRINTING TABLE
____________________
|                   ciao    |
|                 ?:?0?     |
```

Comment: This does not sound right `ptr->next = (symrec*)tabella;` Perhaps you meant `ptr->next = *tabella;`. Also, `ptr->tipo = tipo;` causes a memory leak. The value returned from `malloc()` in the previous line is lost.

Comment: Two issues **(1)** where is `tabella` defined/allocated/filled? **(2)** Where is the `type` typedef or other definition? The following looks suspicious: `ptr->tipo = (type*)malloc(sizeof(type));`, but I cannot tell without seeing the definition. Last (not your problem, but an issue you should correct) **Do NOT cast malloc.** Assuming `type` is properly defined, then: `ptr->tipo = malloc(sizeof(type));` is proper and avoids injecting errors into your code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion so far. I will add the code you asked asap when I'm back home because I'm working now.. I didn't know about the type cast, so I will remove it where not necessary..
Btw `tabella` is allocated in a `symrec * function` where nothing happen but a simple delcaration like `symrec * res; return res;`

Comment: OK thanks to @RSahu, you suggestion worked, problem was indeed `ptr->next = (symrec*)tabella;`..don't know what I was thinking about..
If you write it as answer you will get your right answer dude =) THANK you both for suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not sound right.

```
ptr->next = (symrec*)tabella;
```

Perhaps you meant

```
ptr->next = *tabella;
```

Also,

```
ptr->tipo = tipo;
```

causes a memory leak. The value returned from `malloc()` in the previous line is lost.